# Was the google API oath scope authorisation breached in the example below?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api

The goal of the steps below is to create a custom oath client ID which will be used only for my instance of `rclone`. `rclone` already is registered as an app with google API with it's own set of client ID credentials, but the recommended way is create another set for the sake of performance.

In the [google api developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard) I create a new project called `my-rclone-project`.

Once the project is created I proceed to the `OAuth consent screen` where I choose the type `External`. As I proceed to the `OAuth consent screen` there is a setting paragraps called `Scopes for Google APIs`. Here I leave the default scopes (`email`, `profile`, `openid`) explicitly not selecting the scopes which would allow access to google drive.
I call the application `my-rclone-app` and use the defaults.

After that I go to the `Credentials` screen and do `CREARTE CREDENTIALS -> OAuth client ID`.
I choose the `Desktop app` and name the client `my-rclone-desktop-client`. Finishing this results in the reation of the `Client ID` and `Client secret`. Given the scope selected in the `OAuth consent screen` i would expect that these credentials won't allow the app to ask permision for anything besides what was defined in the scope. So it shouln't be able to ask for permission to access the google drive APIs.

I than proceed to configure the rclone from my pc `rclone config`. I enter the oauth credentials I created in the step above. During the config process I'm asked to define the scope to use when accessing google drive as if the `OAuth consent screen` isn't relevant at all. As the config nears it's end, I'm redirected to the browser where the app is requesting to `See and download all your Google Drive files`. I accept that end end the config with defaults selected.

As I try listing with `./rclone lsd google-drive:` I get an error about the drive API not being enabled with a link in the error on how to enable it. Going on that link and enabling it results in `./rclone lsd google-drive:` listing the content of my drive.

What is the purpose of having to define an `OAuth consent screen` and the API scope as a part of it when the app can request an arbitrary scope completly bypassing the scope selected in the  `OAuth consent screen` setup?

---

<sub>Reference: [Create a client ID in google API](https://rclone.org/drive/#making-your-own-client-id)</sub>

Comment: I am not sure if you have mentioned all the steps. I tried same steps you mentioned and on the oauth prompt it explicitly asks for permissions to read and download files from the drive.

Comment: @DipenShah But it does that even though you haven't explicitly selected the scope which allows API access to google drive, right?

Comment: in my case there wasn't any way to unselect read and download permission. You used 2 for access type during setup, right?

Comment: @DipenShah Not sure what you mean by 2. I'm  talking about the setup before you actually give the permissions. The part called `Scopes for Google APIs` in the `OAuth consent screen`. It ask you to define an API scope, but it seems regardless of what you define there, the app can ask to access whatever it wants eventually.

Comment: Is YOUR APPLICATION calling Google API for authorization or rclone cli? If it is rclone cli, that is a separate app with its own client Id and you can not limit/control what type of access it will request from admin console (you can however pass it as an argument or in config), you can only decide it at the time it opens oauth consent screen

Comment: Verify your account's "Manage third-party access" page to check actual permission rclone have: https://myaccount.google.com/permissions

Comment: @DipenShah I've rephrased the question completely in an attempt to make it cleaner.

Comment: my points still holds and I will elaborate bit more when I get a chance to add them as an answer. Most likely this will answer your question: Your app can still request for more permission than consent screen was configured but  user will see unverified app error and will be on their own if they still wants to proceed:
https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why you want to have custom OAuth consent page?**

In order for you app to use one of Google's auth servers, your application needs some way to be identified by auth servers and that is where **Client ID** and **Client Secret** comes in to play and **consent page** server as a screen on which you application specific information such as application name, contact info, privacy policy, term of use etc. will be displayed to the user.

**What are scopes that you define on consent screen setup?**

On consent screen set up you are supposed to include all possible scopes that you application is going to request from Google APIs, **but that doesn't mean you app is limited to those scopes only**. Scope listed here will be used by Google for application verification purpose and once Google verifies you application, it will no longer display **This app isn't verified** warning page **as long as your app is requesting one of those verified scopes**.

Even after verification, if you application completes verification, requesting any scope access which isn't included in this list will still display **This app isn't verified** warning message.

[image]

and clicking on learn more link will open Google Account help page which clearly states once you provide access to application, when you allow third-party apps to access your Google Account, they can copy and save your data on their own servers. Because Google can’t protect the data on another company’s servers, your data may be subject to greater data security and privacy risks.

> What is the purpose of having to define an OAuth consent screen and the API scope as a part of it when the app can request an arbitrary scope completely bypassing the scope selected in the OAuth consent screen setup?

The main purpose of the **consent screen configuration** is to allow app developer to present information about application it's terms and privacy policy during authorization process. And of course not to have warning once application is verified.

Please refer following link to better understand about unverified apps and scope verification:

1. https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en
2. https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914
3. https://www.gmass.co/blog/five-annoying-issues-google-oauth-scope-verification/
4. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521?p=app_notverified&visit_id=637365968258169095-220403864&rd=2#notverified